# How to escape a column name in Dashboard Variables

Tags: escaping, grafana, grafana-templating

How do I escape the column name 'group'?
Grafana is using this as a filtering keyword rather than the column name.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put double quotes around the group in the where clause, it fixes the issue.